# Airflow: set different schedule intervals for weekdays and weekend

Tags: airflow

**Context** 
I have an airflow DAG that runs jobs on a data warehouse. The DAG runs hourly.
In order to optimise the consumption of the warehouse engine, it makes sense to reduce the refresh frequency during the weekend.

**Question**
How can I change the schedule_interval of a DAG to accommodate two different scheduling based on the weekday:

- During weekday: "hourly every day"
- During weekend: "Every 3 hours every day"

Answer (score -1):

According to cron expression: `0 * * * 1,2,3,4,5` and `0 */3 * * 6,7` for weekends.

Comment: How can you feed this to the schedule_interval variable of the DAG in AirFlow?

Comment: Duplicate DAG's and set those schedule_interval's or use [airflow timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html) with definied logic.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a timetable according to the [docs here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html?highlight=two%20schedule%20intervals) or you can use the following hack to use a duplicate dag and a loop for the tasks

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 3,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),

    }

START_DATE = datetime(2022, 1, 1)

weekend_dag = DAG(
    'weekends',
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    description='This dag runs on weekends',
    schedule_interval='0 */3 * * 6,0',
    start_date=START_DATE,
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example1'],
)

weekday_dag = DAG(
    'weekdays',
    default_args= DEFAULT_ARGS,
    description='This dag runs on weekdays',
    schedule_interval='0 * * * 1-5',
    start_date=START_DATE,
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example2'],
)

dags = {
    'daily_hourly': weekday_dag,
    'weekend_three_hourly': weekend_dag,
}

for dag_name in dags:
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id=f'{dag_name}_task1',
        bash_command='date',
        dag = dags[dag_name])

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id=f'{dag_name}_task2',
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command='sleep 5',
        retries=3,
        dag = dags[dag_name])
```

Comment: This is such an horrible hack that goes against every SE principle. Please do not suggest it :-)